# How to calculate the change using a baseline hour in R?

Tags: r, datetime

I have this data frame

```
library(lubridate)
df <- data.frame(seq(ymd_h("2017-01-01-00"), ymd_h("2020-01-31-24"), by = "hours"))
df$close <- rnorm(nrows(df), 3000, 150)

colnames(df) <- c("date", "close")
df$date <- as.POSIXct(df$date, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
df$hour <- hour(df$date)
df$day <- day(df$date)
df$month <- month(df$date)
df$year <- year(df$date)
```

I want to get the change of close price since the 16 hours. For example, after hour 16 the mean change of price in all the data at hour 18 was...and so on for all the hours. I want to set one hour as a baseline and get the change in price.

This is what I did. First I use lag but I am not sure how to set 16 hours as a baseline. However, this not even give me close to the result I want. The second approach I use lead but I have the same problem:

```
df_2 <- df %>% group_by(year, month, day, hour) %>% 
  mutate(change = (close-lead(close)))
```

In summary, I want to calculate on each day the change in price from hour 16 and then get the mean change on price from 16 hours to the rest of the hours.

Comment: Does the mean has to be taken on a monthly or annual basis?

Comment: Actually, it should be taken by the hour. I want to identify the average change in the data frame for each hour. For example, the average change in the data frame from hour 16 to hour 18. I want to use hour 16 as the baseline and get the difference on the rest of the hours.

Comment: Also, I think you have an error, `rnorm(length(df), 3000, 150)` should be `rnorm(nrows(df), 3000, 150)` I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need around the clock diff:

```r
setDT(df)
df[, date_number := as.numeric(as.Date(ymd_h( sprintf("%d-%d-%dT%d",year,month,day,hour) ) - hours(16))) ]
df[, delta := close - close[ hour == 16 ], .(date_number) ]

head( df, n=48 )
tail( df, n=48 )

df[, .(meanPerHour = mean(delta)), .(hour) ]
```

To do it correctly you need to create the Date object, which you can see in the code, then subtract 16 hours (or add 8), to make 16:00 your new 0:00 , and then cast this back to a Date, and group by that Date's day number (which you get from as.numeric).

The first 48 rows:

```
> head( df, n=48 )
                   date    close hour day month year date_number       delta
 1: 2017-01-01 00:00:00 2924.671    0   1     1 2017       17166          NA
 2: 2017-01-01 01:00:00 3019.730    1   1     1 2017       17166          NA
 3: 2017-01-01 02:00:00 2988.162    2   1     1 2017       17166          NA
 4: 2017-01-01 03:00:00 3133.018    3   1     1 2017       17166          NA
 5: 2017-01-01 04:00:00 3017.546    4   1     1 2017       17166          NA
 6: 2017-01-01 05:00:00 3047.795    5   1     1 2017       17166          NA
 7: 2017-01-01 06:00:00 2912.731    6   1     1 2017       17166          NA
 8: 2017-01-01 07:00:00 3107.180    7   1     1 2017       17166          NA
 9: 2017-01-01 08:00:00 2876.211    8   1     1 2017       17166          NA
10: 2017-01-01 09:00:00 2946.021    9   1     1 2017       17166          NA
11: 2017-01-01 10:00:00 3013.483   10   1     1 2017       17166          NA
12: 2017-01-01 11:00:00 3014.441   11   1     1 2017       17166          NA
13: 2017-01-01 12:00:00 2969.755   12   1     1 2017       17166          NA
14: 2017-01-01 13:00:00 3110.976   13   1     1 2017       17166          NA
15: 2017-01-01 14:00:00 3018.507   14   1     1 2017       17166          NA
16: 2017-01-01 15:00:00 2995.602   15   1     1 2017       17166          NA
17: 2017-01-01 16:00:00 2941.672   16   1     1 2017       17167    0.000000
18: 2017-01-01 17:00:00 3076.628   17   1     1 2017       17167  134.956576
19: 2017-01-01 18:00:00 2862.928   18   1     1 2017       17167  -78.743991
20: 2017-01-01 19:00:00 3346.545   19   1     1 2017       17167  404.872660
21: 2017-01-01 20:00:00 2934.287   20   1     1 2017       17167   -7.385360
22: 2017-01-01 21:00:00 3114.609   21   1     1 2017       17167  172.937229
23: 2017-01-01 22:00:00 3039.294   22   1     1 2017       17167   97.622331
24: 2017-01-01 23:00:00 3116.011   23   1     1 2017       17167  174.338827
25: 2017-01-02 00:00:00 2877.843    0   2     1 2017       17167  -63.828732
26: 2017-01-02 01:00:00 2934.232    1   2     1 2017       17167   -7.439448
27: 2017-01-02 02:00:00 2891.967    2   2     1 2017       17167  -49.705095
28: 2017-01-02 03:00:00 3034.642    3   2     1 2017       17167   92.969817
29: 2017-01-02 04:00:00 2826.341    4   2     1 2017       17167 -115.331282
30: 2017-01-02 05:00:00 3037.061    5   2     1 2017       17167   95.389536
31: 2017-01-02 06:00:00 2986.333    6   2     1 2017       17167   44.661103
32: 2017-01-02 07:00:00 3263.606    7   2     1 2017       17167  321.934480
33: 2017-01-02 08:00:00 2979.311    8   2     1 2017       17167   37.638695
34: 2017-01-02 09:00:00 2983.321    9   2     1 2017       17167   41.649113
35: 2017-01-02 10:00:00 2896.498   10   2     1 2017       17167  -45.174011
36: 2017-01-02 11:00:00 2966.731   11   2     1 2017       17167   25.059003
37: 2017-01-02 12:00:00 3027.436   12   2     1 2017       17167   85.764290
38: 2017-01-02 13:00:00 3062.598   13   2     1 2017       17167  120.926630
39: 2017-01-02 14:00:00 3159.810   14   2     1 2017       17167  218.138486
40: 2017-01-02 15:00:00 3145.530   15   2     1 2017       17167  203.858440
41: 2017-01-02 16:00:00 2984.756   16   2     1 2017       17168    0.000000
42: 2017-01-02 17:00:00 3210.481   17   2     1 2017       17168  225.724909
43: 2017-01-02 18:00:00 2733.484   18   2     1 2017       17168 -251.271959
44: 2017-01-02 19:00:00 3093.430   19   2     1 2017       17168  108.674494
45: 2017-01-02 20:00:00 2921.657   20   2     1 2017       17168  -63.098117
46: 2017-01-02 21:00:00 3198.335   21   2     1 2017       17168  213.579029
47: 2017-01-02 22:00:00 2945.484   22   2     1 2017       17168  -39.271663
48: 2017-01-02 23:00:00 3197.860   23   2     1 2017       17168  213.104247
```

The last 48 records:

```
> tail( df, n=48 )
     date    close hour day month year date_number         delta
 1: 18290 3170.775    1  30     1 2020       18290  201.47027428
 2: 18290 3293.403    2  30     1 2020       18290  324.09870453
 3: 18290 2940.591    3  30     1 2020       18290  -28.71382979
 4: 18290 2922.411    4  30     1 2020       18290  -46.89312915
 5: 18290 3237.419    5  30     1 2020       18290  268.11402422
 6: 18290 2989.678    6  30     1 2020       18290   20.37332637
 7: 18290 2932.777    7  30     1 2020       18290  -36.52746038
 8: 18291 3188.269    8  30     1 2020       18290  218.96474627
 9: 18291 3003.327    9  30     1 2020       18290   34.02206527
10: 18291 2969.222   10  30     1 2020       18290   -0.08292166
11: 18291 2848.911   11  30     1 2020       18290 -120.39313851
12: 18291 2892.804   12  30     1 2020       18290  -76.50054871
13: 18291 3064.894   13  30     1 2020       18290   95.58913403
14: 18291 3172.009   14  30     1 2020       18290  202.70445747
15: 18291 3373.631   15  30     1 2020       18290  404.32650780
16: 18291 3019.765   16  30     1 2020       18291    0.00000000
17: 18291 2748.688   17  30     1 2020       18291 -271.07660267
18: 18291 2718.065   18  30     1 2020       18291 -301.70056024
19: 18291 2817.891   19  30     1 2020       18291 -201.87390563
20: 18291 3086.820   20  30     1 2020       18291   67.05492016
21: 18291 2972.657   21  30     1 2020       18291  -47.10804222
22: 18291 3009.258   22  30     1 2020       18291  -10.50687269
23: 18291 2949.268   23  30     1 2020       18291  -70.49745611
24: 18291 3032.938    0  31     1 2020       18291   13.17296251
25: 18291 3267.187    1  31     1 2020       18291  247.42241735
26: 18291 2984.129    2  31     1 2020       18291  -35.63610546
27: 18291 3053.728    3  31     1 2020       18291   33.96259834
28: 18291 3290.451    4  31     1 2020       18291  270.68616991
29: 18291 2875.921    5  31     1 2020       18291 -143.84421823
30: 18291 3159.612    6  31     1 2020       18291  139.84677795
31: 18291 2798.017    7  31     1 2020       18291 -221.74778788
32: 18292 2833.522    8  31     1 2020       18291 -186.24270860
33: 18292 3184.870    9  31     1 2020       18291  165.10465470
34: 18292 3037.279   10  31     1 2020       18291   17.51427029
35: 18292 3260.309   11  31     1 2020       18291  240.54407728
36: 18292 3178.804   12  31     1 2020       18291  159.03915248
37: 18292 2905.164   13  31     1 2020       18291 -114.60150340
38: 18292 2928.120   14  31     1 2020       18291  -91.64555778
39: 18292 2975.566   15  31     1 2020       18291  -44.19924163
40: 18292 3060.792   16  31     1 2020       18292    0.00000000
41: 18292 2916.899   17  31     1 2020       18292 -143.89373840
42: 18292 3297.537   18  31     1 2020       18292  236.74429212
43: 18292 3208.996   19  31     1 2020       18292  148.20392802
44: 18292 2791.129   20  31     1 2020       18292 -269.66375428
45: 18292 2842.001   21  31     1 2020       18292 -218.79120834
46: 18292 2992.381   22  31     1 2020       18292  -68.41127630
47: 18292 3189.018   23  31     1 2020       18292  128.22565814
48: 18292 2962.099    0   1     2 2020       18292  -98.69355677
```

The average per hour:

```
> df[, .(meanPerHour = mean(delta)), .(hour) ]
    hour meanPerHour
 1:    0   3.5877077
 2:    1   1.3695897
 3:    2   0.1010658
 4:    3   1.4441742
 5:    4  -3.0837907
 6:    5  -3.1353593
 7:    6  11.3738058
 8:    7   4.7171345
 9:    8   5.0449846
10:    9   1.3226027
11:   10  -2.3716443
12:   11   1.4710920
13:   12  -4.8875706
14:   13   4.7203754
15:   14   2.3528875
16:   15   2.3075150
17:   16   0.0000000
18:   17  -2.1353366
19:   18   4.5127309
20:   19   5.2032461
21:   20   3.8043017
22:   21   3.7928297
23:   22  -3.9258290
24:   23   3.0638861
```

And in the end, a neat function:

```r
average.by.hour.by.reference <- function( df, hrs=16 ) {

    df <- as.data.table(df)
    df[, date_number := as.numeric(as.Date(ymd_h( sprintf("%d-%d-%dT%d",year,month,day,hour) ) - hours(hrs))) ]
    df[, delta := close - close[ hour == hrs ], .(date_number) ]
    
    return( df[, .(meanPerHour = mean(delta,na.rm=TRUE)), .(hour) ] )
    
}

average.by.hour.by.reference( df, 16 ) # produces the above results
```

### Ironically

You can get, the same, or close enough for real application most likely, by not bothering with the date-wise grouping and just do a global *group by hour* and subtract from that what ever hour you want as reference.

(but then we wouldn't get to show all this fancy code!)

Comment: Can I use this daily? For example for every day if I use the hour 0 as the baseline can I calculate this in a daily timeframe so the mean for the hour 0 should be 0?

Comment: It was tricker than one might first suspect. the average of the 16th hour is 0 , as it should be now.

Comment: You can use the code above to calculate for 0:00 as the reference instead of 16:00 , just take out the `- hours(16)` part, or change it to `- hours(x)` , and put it in a function so you can adjust the reference hour as you like

Comment: Also if it's okay with you, the first day calculates the delta from the first record in the set, not necessarily at hour 16:00 - I can change that if you like

Comment: That would be great!!

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table` you can try the following to get the difference between the baseline and the a price after 16.

```
df <- data.frame(seq(ymd_h("2017-01-01-00"), ymd_h("2020-01-31-24"), by = "hours"))
set.seed(56789)
df$close <- rnorm(nrow(df), 3000, 150)
colnames(df) <- c("date", "close")
df$date <- as.POSIXct(df$date, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
df$hour <- hour(df$date)
df$day <- day(df$date)
df$month <- month(df$date)
df$year <- year(df$date)
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[,dummy:= ifelse(hour>=16,1,0), .(day,month,year)] #building temporary dummy variable
df[dummy==1, Difference:= close-close[1],.(day,month,year)] # computing only when dummy=1
df[1:24,] first 24 rows

                  date    close hour day month year dummy Difference
 1: 2017-01-01 00:00:00 3159.493    0   1     1 2017     0         NA
 2: 2017-01-01 01:00:00 3029.092    1   1     1 2017     0         NA
 3: 2017-01-01 02:00:00 2944.042    2   1     1 2017     0         NA
 4: 2017-01-01 03:00:00 3234.751    3   1     1 2017     0         NA
 5: 2017-01-01 04:00:00 2900.514    4   1     1 2017     0         NA
 6: 2017-01-01 05:00:00 2733.769    5   1     1 2017     0         NA
 7: 2017-01-01 06:00:00 3101.770    6   1     1 2017     0         NA
 8: 2017-01-01 07:00:00 2981.632    7   1     1 2017     0         NA
 9: 2017-01-01 08:00:00 2913.672    8   1     1 2017     0         NA
10: 2017-01-01 09:00:00 2876.495    9   1     1 2017     0         NA
11: 2017-01-01 10:00:00 3025.853   10   1     1 2017     0         NA
12: 2017-01-01 11:00:00 3135.209   11   1     1 2017     0         NA
13: 2017-01-01 12:00:00 3038.329   12   1     1 2017     0         NA
14: 2017-01-01 13:00:00 3227.153   13   1     1 2017     0         NA
15: 2017-01-01 14:00:00 3069.497   14   1     1 2017     0         NA
16: 2017-01-01 15:00:00 2988.749   15   1     1 2017     0         NA
17: 2017-01-01 16:00:00 2920.402   16   1     1 2017     1    0.00000
18: 2017-01-01 17:00:00 2756.129   17   1     1 2017     1 -164.27264
19: 2017-01-01 18:00:00 2945.021   18   1     1 2017     1   24.61939
20: 2017-01-01 19:00:00 3078.004   19   1     1 2017     1  157.60205
21: 2017-01-01 20:00:00 3239.770   20   1     1 2017     1  319.36791
22: 2017-01-01 21:00:00 3045.156   21   1     1 2017     1  124.75450
23: 2017-01-01 22:00:00 2793.858   22   1     1 2017     1 -126.54371
24: 2017-01-01 23:00:00 3054.496   23   1     1 2017     1  134.09401
                   date    close hour day month year dummy Difference
```

Then to compute the average you will need.

```
df[dummy==1, .(Average= mean(Difference)), .(day, month, year)]
      day month year    Average
   1:   1     1 2017   58.70269
   2:   2     1 2017   80.47927
   3:   3     1 2017 -103.96512
   4:   4     1 2017  -26.52648
   5:   5     1 2017  112.79842
  ---                          
1122:  27     1 2020  -37.89037
1123:  28     1 2020  107.96715
1124:  29     1 2020  222.18109
1125:  30     1 2020  236.18325
1126:  31     1 2020  107.96395
```

To take the mean hourly you have different possibilities:

```
df[dummy==1, .(Average= mean(Difference)), .(hour)]#This takes the average across all the times periods, this can be thought as the hourly mean
   hour     Average
1:   16   0.0000000
2:   17 -13.6811620
3:   18   0.9756538
4:   19   1.0668213
5:   20  -2.9194445
6:   21  -4.1216115
7:   22  -8.7311824
8:   23   5.6657656

df[dummy==1, .(Average= mean(Difference)), .(hour,day)]#This takes the average hourly per day
     hour day    Average
  1:   16   1   0.000000
  2:   17   1  -7.226656
  3:   18   1  13.162067
  4:   19   1 -59.917710
  5:   20   1   1.941420
 ---                    
244:   19  31 -31.069330
245:   20  31 -80.659022
246:   21  31 -14.458324
247:   22  31 -56.760001
248:   23  31 -98.356176
df[dummy==1, .(Average= mean(Difference)), .(hour,month)]#This takes the average across hourly per month
    hour month       Average
 1:   16     1   0.000000000
 2:   17     1  -4.618350490
 3:   18     1  40.095826732
 4:   19     1  51.049164347
 5:   20     1  47.760496506
 6:   21     1  28.985260025
 7:   22     1  21.453695738
 8:   23     1  43.921050387
 9:   16     2   0.000000000
10:   17     2  24.000082289
11:   18     2   2.371547684
12:   19     2   3.065889216
13:   20     2  30.568486748
14:   21     2  -7.283307589
15:   22     2   4.123056028
16:   23     2  16.827384126
17:   16     3   0.000000000
18:   17     3 -16.011701993
19:   18     3   6.322605325
20:   19     3 -29.855560457
21:   20     3 -13.706427976
22:   21     3  -4.131364097
23:   22     3 -25.854584963
24:   23     3 -18.667824140
25:   16     4   0.000000000
26:   17     4 -20.303835780
27:   18     4   5.908122132
28:   19     4  -8.934949281
29:   20     4 -21.563964556
30:   21     4 -26.050153530
31:   22     4 -16.182759246
32:   23     4  -0.367104020
33:   16     5   0.000000000
34:   17     5 -83.744224359
35:   18     5 -44.324985588
36:   19     5 -13.327785591
37:   20     5 -14.258074789
38:   21     5 -36.776426101
39:   22     5 -40.702102505
40:   23     5 -26.994831954
41:   16     6   0.000000000
42:   17     6  10.047707916
43:   18     6   3.580200953
44:   19     6   8.229738674
45:   20     6   2.976396675
46:   21     6  14.575098983
47:   22     6  12.378672353
48:   23     6   4.663891884
49:   16     7   0.000000000
50:   17     7  19.338362910
51:   18     7  31.278370567
52:   19     7  12.295521900
53:   20     7 -36.728712097
54:   21     7  25.194723060
55:   22     7 -24.817961383
56:   23     7  -6.270365221
57:   16     8   0.000000000
58:   17     8  13.125994953
59:   18     8  15.364473667
60:   19     8  29.268466966
61:   20     8  44.668839826
62:   21     8  14.083177674
63:   22     8  17.876126102
64:   23     8  50.563302963
65:   16     9   0.000000000
66:   17     9 -55.277687661
67:   18     9  -5.648068231
68:   19     9  12.181088927
69:   20     9 -42.631881383
70:   21     9 -39.224046003
71:   22     9 -24.291235470
72:   23     9   3.112446527
73:   16    10   0.000000000
74:   17    10   9.087632052
75:   18    10 -12.014161643
76:   19    10 -10.884415174
77:   20    10  18.022160926
78:   21    10  31.348117569
79:   22    10  29.875655193
80:   23    10  28.086021752
81:   16    11   0.000000000
82:   17    11 -25.057459470
83:   18    11   0.745030363
84:   19    11 -23.835528943
85:   20    11 -22.762853780
86:   21    11  -0.005295847
87:   22    11 -37.868714610
88:   23    11 -13.091041985
89:   16    12   0.000000000
90:   17    12 -35.291817797
91:   18    12 -44.854066421
92:   19    12 -33.453450088
93:   20    12 -43.362749669
94:   21    12 -62.620521565
95:   22    12 -30.582971909
96:   23    12 -26.379698528
    hour month       Average
> df[dummy==1, .(Average= mean(Difference)), .(hour,year)]#This takes the average across hourly per year
    hour year      Average
 1:   16 2017   0.00000000
 2:   17 2017   0.01183124
 3:   18 2017  -4.00877399
 4:   19 2017   7.94893418
 5:   20 2017   5.78072996
 6:   21 2017  -4.38927559
 7:   22 2017  -4.32599586
 8:   23 2017  10.48530717
 9:   16 2018   0.00000000
10:   17 2018 -32.52958909
11:   18 2018 -10.05792694
12:   19 2018 -11.98513416
13:   20 2018 -19.05685234
14:   21 2018  -7.55054075
15:   22 2018 -19.68501405
16:   23 2018  -6.70448412
17:   16 2019   0.00000000
18:   17 2019  -8.12025319
19:   18 2019  13.66533695
20:   19 2019   5.00197941
21:   20 2019  -2.37632221
22:   21 2019  -2.06337033
23:   22 2019  -4.47205960
24:   23 2019  11.88583864
25:   16 2020   0.00000000
26:   17 2020 -18.45530363
27:   18 2020  40.16399935
28:   19 2020  27.37843018
29:   20 2020  78.25315556
30:   21 2020  15.16866359
31:   22 2020  18.22609517
32:   23 2020  21.33292148
    hour year      Average

df[dummy==1, .(Average= mean(Difference)), .(hour,day,month)]#This takes the average hourly per month and so on
      hour day month     Average
   1:   16   1     1    0.000000
   2:   17   1     1 -121.842677
   3:   18   1     1  -58.055247
   4:   19   1     1 -116.444000
   5:   20   1     1    5.414297
  ---                           
2916:   19  31    12 -162.743923
2917:   20  31    12  -60.029392
2918:   21  31    12 -289.992006
2919:   22  31    12  -26.354495
2920:   23  31    12 -171.848433
```

Comment: shouldn't the small hours through the night also reference last 16:00?

Comment: Yes. That's what I need. I want to get also a reference for the night hours. Maybe something until 9am of the next day. Also, I need the average by the hour, is that possible?

Comment: I understood OP is considering to obtain the difference in a day that starts at 0:00 and ends at 23:00

Comment: Yes. Don't worry is not a problem. How can I get the mean of the difference hourly instead of daily?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what do you really mean by hourly; of course we can get the hourly mean but it implies you may need a higher level (day, month, or year) to take the mean from, so if you say the mean at hour 18, is it across all day 1, 2, ...31? or  all months 1, ... ,12? or year 2017 ... 2020? Check my updated code to see this.